How to account for disproportionate group sizes?
In a sample of 1090 individuals (men = 1005, women = 85), can we reasonably find gender differences despite disproportionately more number of men than women in the sample?
We are currently using the following model in R:
lmer(y ~ x * gender + (1|individual_id), data = df)

Some have critiqued that with such small number of females, there is likely to be type 1 or 2 errors with using the above regression.
Is there any way to address such concerns in the mixed model?

What data do you have? It looks like you have repeated measures, but how many repeats? What is x? How is it distributed? How big a difference do you expect? How well is x measured?

A sample of 1005 men and 85 women is going to be better at correctly identifying gender differences than one of 85 men and 85 women.

I would rather be concerned about possible selection effects and the generalizability of your results to the entire population. Last I checked, there were about as many men as women, so if your sample is skewed to the degree here, the 85 women in your sample may not be representative of "women in general".

Tell the critics they're wrong? :-)

In general, for a reasonable model framework (including mixed models) where the assumptions are not too badly violated, the type 1 error rate shouldn't depend on the sample size or balance in the data set.*
It may be that "type 2 errors" (failing to detect a true effect) are common because you don't have data on enough females (this is more or less equivalent to 'insufficient power'), but I'm not sure what your alternatives are. Go get more data? (Often this is not an option.) Don't do the analysis at all? (Not generally an option people like.)
"can we reasonably find gender differences?"  That depends on the sizes of effects you're expecting. You can look at the "Power analysis and simulation" section of the mixed models task view, e.g. the simr package (basic vignette here) to run some simulations based on the effect sizes you're hoping to detect and see what your power to detect them is ...
how should you "account for" lack of balance?  There is no need to do so, this is taken care of in the regression framework.


* I'm among the people who believe that "type 1 errors" never happen in the real world, because they are the probability of rejecting $H_0$ when $H_0$ is true, and in most situations outside of theoretical physics $H_0$ is never true ...

very helpful, indeed!
